# How to get all of the one-to-many entities in a GET request with Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

```
  @GetMapping("/tutorials")
      public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> getAllTutorials(@RequestParam(required = false) String title) {
        try {
          List<Tutorial> tutorials = new ArrayList<Tutorial>();

          if (title == null)
            tutorialRepository.findAll().forEach(tutorials::add);
          else
            tutorialRepository.findByTitleContaining(title).forEach(tutorials::add);

          if (tutorials.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
          }

          return new ResponseEntity<>(tutorials, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
      }
```

I am trying to return all tutorials and in each tutorials I want the videos associated with each tutorials to appear when I make a GET request, but I can't get it working for some reason. Is there anything wrong with the mapping?

```
package com.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tutorials")
public class Tutorial {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "published")
    private boolean published;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "video_id")
    private List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tutorial() {

    }

    public Tutorial(String title, String description, boolean published) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.published = published;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }

    public void setPublished(boolean isPublished) {
        this.published = isPublished;
    }
}
```

I am expecting a field called videos which holds an array of video instances associated with each tutorials, but I don't get anything. I only get the fields associated with the tutorials making the one-to-many mapping useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Video> getVideos() {
    return videos;
}
```

I forgot to put a getter for videos that's why it wasn't working. Most tutorials don't show the getters and setters and assume you know that they are required in order for the mapping to work properly.